# Marklogic DataHub Harmonization flow failure

Tags: java, marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I have a java application thats using the marklogic datahub API. I am running a flow on two separate entities.  During the harmonization process, one entity passes fine while the other fails. This just seemed to start happening out of the blue as it was working fine earlier and I do not believe I made any changes that would effect this. I have datahub 5.0.2 deployed locally.  Here is the code for the flow.

```
FlowRunner flowRunner = flowManager.newFlowRunner().withFlow(harmonizeFlow)
                    .withBatchSize(4)
                    .withThreadCount(10).withOptions(null)
                    .withDestinationDatabase("final")
                    .onItemComplete((String jobId, String itemId) -> log.info("Job passed with job id :{} item id :{}",
                            jobId, itemId))
                    .onItemFailed((String jobId, String itemId) -> log.info("Job failed with job id :{} item id :{}",
                            jobId, itemId));
```

here is the output for the two entities:

> Job passed with job id :b9f105d0-df3c-4f79-8b3b-dc7b3a6dfcab item id xxxxxxx
>
> Job failed with job id :cda1ac16-32ba-4d29-a135-dbed6e918057 item id xxxxxxx

Why might this be happening? Both entites were configured the same with similar content.sjs files. There is not really a stack trace I can use to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: What steps are being run by your flow, and what are they doing?

Comment: currently I have it moving documents from one database to the other, doing the harmonization process for each entity. Thats all I am trying to get working right now.

Comment: Is it a custom step, or a mapping step, or something else?

Comment: Its a Mapping step

Comment: Some other things to check - does the problem happen when you run the flow via Gradle or QuickStart? What happens if you try more than 2 entities? Can you try the latest 5.0.x version, or upgrade to 5.1.0 or 5.2.0, and see if get the same error? Also, try clearing the jobs database, then run your flow again. Look at the job/batch documents created in the jobs database for more error information.